# How to Validate date and time using html5

Tags: html

I am use html5 feature for getting date and time which is follw

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="dtl" id='dd'>
```

It work fine but I want to start with `current date and time`,previous `date and time` should not allowed for a use.

so please suggest me to how to do it.

Comment: So what are you asking? You want the time right now? What previous date and time? Are you just desiring date and time validation?

Comment: I want only date and time from now I do not want past date and time

Comment: whether  it  use future date time

Comment: So what you want is to preload the date and time with the current time and make it readonly so the user can not input the time?

Comment: This may help: 
http://sixrevisions.com/html5/new-html5-form-input-types/

Comment: Exactly I want,Backtrack

Comment: Note that as soon as you initialize the control, its value will be invalid because it's already in the past. You may need to refine your requirements more before you continue.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably gonna need JavaScript for this. Create a date and assign it your [`datatime-local input`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.datetime-local.html#input.datetime-local) field:

```
var date = new Date(),
    dd = document.getElementById('dd');
dd.value = date.toISOString();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jzAGR/)

To require a date in the future, you could also modify the [`min` attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.datetime-local.html#input.datetime-local.attrs.min) of your input, but that's not going to work because to this day no major browser to this date supports this type of input. You might be better off using a JavaScript-based date picker for this job.